# Asymptotic analysis for sum

Tags: analysis

Let $f,g,h,j$ be functions of $x$.

Suppose $f\sim g$ as, say $x\to\infty$ and $h\sim j$ as $x\to\infty$ which, by definition, means that
$$
f-g=\mathcal{o}(g)\text{ and }h-j=\mathcal{o}(j)\textrm{ as }x\to\infty.
$$

Does this imply that $f +h\sim g+j$ as $x\to\infty$.

---

I would think so. It is to show that
$$
f+h - (g+j)=\mathcal{o}(g+j), x\to\infty.
$$
So let $\varepsilon >0$. Then
$$
\lvert f+h-(g+j)\rvert=\lvert f-g+h-j\rvert\leqslant\lvert f-g\rvert+\lvert h-j\rvert\leqslant \varepsilon g+\varepsilon j=\varepsilon (g+j)
$$
for all $x>X$ for some $X:=\max\{X_1,X_2\}$, where
$$
\lvert f-g\rvert\leqslant \varepsilon g~\forall x>X_1
$$
and 
$$
\lvert h-j\rvert\leqslant\varepsilon j~\forall x>X_2
$$
where $X_1,X_2$ exist by assumption.

But this should mean exactly that $f+g\sim h+j$ as $x\to\infty$.

However, I am not sure. Maybe there is some counterexample as it usually is the case when I try to prove things like this.

Comment: If you have positivity assumptions, it works. Without that, let $f = g \colon x \mapsto x$, $h \colon x \mapsto -x + 1$, $j \colon -x + 1/x$ for a counterexample.

Comment: What do you mean with positivity assumptions? In your example, I get that $\lvert f+h-(g+j)\rvert=1-\frac{1}{x}$ and $g+j=\frac{1}{x}$. Hence the first expression cannot be smaller than 1.

Comment: By "positivity assumptions" I mean an assumption/condition that $f,g,h,j$ are positive functions. If they are, then no cancellation like in my example can occur, and you have $f + h \sim g + j$. If the signs of the functions can be different, cancellation may occur and then you need not have asymptotic equality.

Comment: Thanks, got it.